# What is missing from this GeoTIFF to allow me to convert to EPSG:3857?

Tags: gdal

I have a source online for GeoTIFF files that I wish to convert to EPSG:3857 for Mapbox. (Flood Data for the United States.) A sample file is here :
(http://flash.ou.edu/flash_web/maxthres/maxthres.20200712.012000.tif).

When I run gdalinfo on the above file, I get this output :

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: maxthres.20200712.012000.tif
Size is 7000, 3500
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: datum not found
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: datum not found
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["NAD83",
    DATUM["unnamed",
        ELLIPSOID["unretrievable - using WGS84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4269]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-130.000000000000000,55.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.010000000000000,-0.010000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=EF5 v1.0
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=DEFLATE
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-130.0000000,  55.0000000) (130d 0' 0.00"W, 55d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-130.0000000,  20.0000000) (130d 0' 0.00"W, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right ( -60.0000000,  55.0000000) ( 60d 0' 0.00"W, 55d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right ( -60.0000000,  20.0000000) ( 60d 0' 0.00"W, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Center      ( -95.0000000,  37.5000000) ( 95d 0' 0.00"W, 37d30' 0.00"N)
Band 1 Block=7000x20 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999
```

I was able to find a training manual showing how the development team that creates QGIS to create these geoTIFs, and it looked like it was in EPSG:4326. With that, I tried the command :

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 maxthres.20200712.012000.tif maxthres.20200712.012000-projected.tif
```

This is very close, however some of the pixels are off. (I may be wrong about 4326 too). The following output is also presented:

```
Creating output file that is 6553P x 4279L.
Processing maxthres.20200712.012000.tif [1/1] : 0ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: datum not found
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: datum not found
```

Is there some command I am missing, or do I need more information to be able to convert this properly?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the GDAL version (i.e. `gdalinfo --version`).

Comment: don't use `-s_srs` at all - then GDAL will use the defined projection in the file

Answer (score 1):

Your file may be missing some information but it does tell us that the `Coordinate System is: GEOGCRS["NAD83"`

Looking at the EPSG Registry (http://www.epsg-registry.org/) we can find out (searching for NAD83 as a CRS) that the correct EPSG code is 4269.

WKT (http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4269) gives us:

```
GEODCRS["NAD83",
  DATUM["North American Datum 1983",
    ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
  CS[ellipsoidal,2],
    AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1]],
    AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2]],
    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252],
  ID["EPSG",4269]]
```

I loaded the TIFF into QGIS using EPSG::4269 as the project CRS and loaded a global backdrop as below, and to me it looks like it's located in the correct location; backdrop is world geology so it might be less obvious to others.

[image: Tiff in QGIS]

QGIS will happily export to EPSG:3857, and the new image gives me the following information.

```
gdalinfo -proj4 maxthres.20200712.012000_new.tif 

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: maxthres.20200712.012000_new.tif
Size is 7000, 3519
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["X",EAST],
    AXIS["Y",NORTH],
    EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs"],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
PROJ.4 string is:
'+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs'
Origin = (-14471533.803099999204278,7361866.112900000065565)
Pixel Size = (1113.194907928571411,-1446.102638817846127)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-14471533.803, 7361866.113) (130d 0' 0.00"W, 55d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-14471533.803, 2273030.927) (130d 0' 0.00"W, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Upper Right (-6679169.448, 7361866.113) ( 60d 0' 0.00"W, 55d 0' 0.00"N)
Lower Right (-6679169.448, 2273030.927) ( 60d 0' 0.00"W, 20d 0' 0.00"N)
Center      (-10575351.625, 4817448.520) ( 95d 0' 0.00"W, 39d39'55.71"N)
Band 1 Block=7000x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-9999
```

To use GDAL directly you can use:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:4269 -t_srs epsg:3857 maxthres.20200712.012000.tif maxthres.20200712.012000_newer.tiff
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, and thank you for the clear explanation. However, how would this be done in GDAL? (as how I was trying to do with my code in my question). Surely this is very close to being correct now